# Execute graph API Facebook [send app request]

Tags: php, facebook

I want to send app request to user of app Facebook.

`https://graph.facebook.com/myid_facebook/apprequests?message=`test`&data=`INSERT_STRING_DATA`&access_token=XXXXXXX&method=post`

I've tried using curl, but it's not to work ...

This is my source code

```
$app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$app_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/endif.tc" .
        "/apprequests?message=’pak nurrohman memberi anda tugas’" .
        "&data=’INSERT_STRING_DATA’&access_token=" .
        $this->facebook->getAccessToken() . "&method=post";

$result = file_get_html($apprequest_url);
echo ("Request id number: " . $result['request']);
```

**file_get_html** is function to load another page using curl.

and this error is:

```
"failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"
```

I want to execute this graph on php side..is there any solution for me?

I'm sorry, my bad english.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because of the url and the fact you cant just method=post.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/endif.tc"
```

Use This Code Instead For A Proper URL

```
$user_id = 'endif.tc';
$data = 'test';
$message = 'test request';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".urlencode($user_id)."/apprequests" .
    "?message=".urlencode($message).
    "&data=".urlencode($data).
    "&access_token=".$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
```

The other issue may be that file_get_contents does not POST the data to the page. If you wish to post the data you might need to use the cURL library.

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in your urlencode method, when you encode $data.

Comment: Thank you for everything ... now it's successful..

but you must write the "&method=post" to send app request..

Comment: I was unaware of the method=post requirement. It has been a while since I did any facebook work. Glad I could help!

Comment: if you are using curl, I guess it works without "&method=post".

Comment: provided you are using the method POST.

Comment: help me please, I get some problem and please go to here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595517/failed-to-create-any-app-request
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595692/send-app-request