# send app request

Tags: facebook

I have successfully send app requests as shown below

[image: app request]

but I want to send a request like the following picture app. how do I send it? what can I use graph?

[image: app request]

Answer (score 1):

Only user-to-user requests will generate the notification you want. You should utilize the Facebook Request dialog to send a user-to-user request.